# Lasagne basic example not working?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, lasagne, nolearn

I went through the install steps for lasagne, straight from the lasagne docs. And now I am running the following example:
https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/examples/mnist.py

The output expected is shown on the tutorial page of the lasagne docs.

But, so far it is hanging at the line "Starting training...". It has been stuck at this line for quite some time.

are there any obvious things that could be wrong with my setup?

I downloaded MinGW gcc and have the environment variables set up ok for it as well as theano using the following from pip:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/v0.1/requirements.txt

I also used pip to download lasagne, have numpy and scipy downloaded also.

Comment: What OS are you using and are you running it on a GPU?

Comment: How long have you been waiting? It can take a couple of minutes to compile the computational graph depending on system and size of network. Could there be read/write problems to your home directory?